# Indolence vs Laziness - Is there any difference in usage?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

They appear to have practically identical definitions. Is there any reason to use "indolence" over its more common counterpart or is "indolence" obsolete?

Comment: "Is there any reason to use "indolence" over its more common counterpart"

Well the reason would be so people can understand you.  I can't answer as to why laziness is more common, but it is so much more popular that few people would understand indolence.

Comment: I would use *indolent* to describe somebody who can't be bothered exerting themselves. I would use *lazy* to describe somebody who can't be bothered doing what I want them to do. Not an answer, because this only my understanding, and others may use the words differently.

Comment: I'd use *indolence* only as related to an **idle** state: bored, low energy, passive, but not because of being lazy. Laziness is more ... active, in not wanting to take action. But I'm too lazy to ever use the word indolence.

Answer (score 1):

Being lazy is bad and a moral failing. Even used jokingly "I'm too lazy to make toast today" is making fun of yourself. Whereas indolence isn't bad -- it's similar to relaxing. It's associated with the rich, who don't work because they don't need to. A non-lazy person could work hard and rightfully enjoy a day of indolence at the spa, whereas being lazy and going to the spa means there's something more useful you know you should be doing.

And, of course, lazy is much more common and people like to mix up words. "My husband is lazy" is just a complaint, whereas "Tony is ... indolent" is starting a conversation.

Comment: "A lazy day in bed" if it's not a habit, is not a necessarily negative thing. Please support your claim that *indolence* has more positive connotations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, you could spend a day "taking it easy" in bed, which feels like a considered decision. Doesn't the choice of "lazy" suggest you had something else planned for your day off, or something you feel is better, but you're just now feeling ... lazy?